# Iterate two loops, hover one button, change corresponding element

Tags: jquery

I have two loops, one with a set of buttons and the other with a set of spans. When I hover over one of the buttons, I want the corresponding span to change colour. They both have a count on them going from 0 upwards, that should tie the two items together.

This is my attempt, where am I going wrong? It doesn't seem to do anything.

```
$('.toggle').each(function () {
            var item = $(this).data();
            $('.feature-dot[data-number="'+ item +'"]').css('background-colour', 'green');
        }, function () {
            $('.feature-dot[data-number="'+ item +'"]').css('background-colour', 'yellow');
        });
```

Button loop:

```
        <li>
            <a class="toggle dot-link-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-number="<?php echo $count; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?> <span class="opener">+</span><span class="closer">-</span></a>
            <span class="inner">
                <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
            </span>
        </li>
```

Dot loop (corresponding items):

```
<span class="feature-dot dot-<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-number="<?php echo $counter; ?>" style="top:<?php echo $top; ?>px;left:<?php echo $left; ?>px;"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the key to [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method, use it like

```
var item = $(this).data('number');
```

And had to use `.hover()` function instead of `.each()` to attach event handler.

```
$('.toggle').hover(function () {
    var item = $(this).data('number');
    $('.feature-dot[data-number="' + item + '"]').css('background-color', 'green');
}, function () {
    var item = $(this).data('number');
    $('.feature-dot[data-number="' + item + '"]').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: That worked! Great thanks. Colour spelt wrongly for CSS... such a stupid mistake by me!!